# RenderTarget->GetSize not working

Tags: c++, gcc, windows-7-x64, direct2d

To learn myself Direct2D i'm following [this example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd370994%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) from the MSDN.

I have however one issue. The call `D2D1_SIZE_F rtSize = m_pRenderTarget->GetSize();` allways returns a size of 0,0 and in the debugger causes an exception on the `DrawLine` call. If I leave out the GetSize() call and fill in the D2D1_SIZE_F structure with valid values it works.

The relevant code for initializing the render target is:

```
    RECT rc;
    GetClientRect(m_hwnd, &rc);

    D2D1_SIZE_U size = D2D1::SizeU(
        rc.right - rc.left,
        rc.bottom - rc.top
        );

    // Create a Direct2D render target.
    hr = m_pDirect2dFactory->CreateHwndRenderTarget(
        D2D1::RenderTargetProperties(),
        D2D1::HwndRenderTargetProperties(m_hwnd, size),
        &m_pRenderTarget
        );
```

I have verified with the debugger that valid values are past in size.

The part of the drawing code where GetSize is called:

```
    m_pRenderTarget->BeginDraw();

    m_pRenderTarget->SetTransform(D2D1::Matrix3x2F::Identity());

    m_pRenderTarget->Clear(D2D1::ColorF(D2D1::ColorF::White));
    D2D1_SIZE_F rtSize = m_pRenderTarget->GetSize();
    // Draw a grid background.
    int width = static_cast<int>(rtSize.width);
    int height = static_cast<int>(rtSize.height);

    for (int x = 0; x < width; x += 10)
    {
        m_pRenderTarget->DrawLine(
            D2D1::Point2F(static_cast<FLOAT>(x), 0.0f),
            D2D1::Point2F(static_cast<FLOAT>(x), rtSize.height),
            m_pLightSlateGrayBrush,
            0.5f
            );
    }
```

So my question is why does GetSize() return 0,0 and causes an AV later on?

BTW: I'm using:
Windows 7 Ultimate 64-bits
Code::Blocks IDE
TDM-GCC-64 gcc compiler v4.8.1
I'm compiling in Unicode mode `#define UNICODE`
Problem occurs regardles if I compile to 32-bits or 64-bits (yes I made a few minor adjustments for 64-bits mode to make sure I had a valid pointer to the application object in WndProc)

Comment: Exception or assertion? What is the exact error message? What is the minimal code causing issues?

Comment: An Access Violation on the call to DrawLine.

Comment: Please go and read the FAQ. In particular, quote the *whole* error message and then edit your question to contain that info. Then, extract a minimal example from your code. As it stands, it's hard to tell what is relevant and what isn't.

Comment: There is no error message, just the message: 'Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.' from the debugger. If I run it without the debugger I just get a blank window (no messages). When I don't use the GetSize call (and determine the size by another method) everything is fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why does GetSize() return 0,0 and causes an AV later on?

Because the call to GetSize generated by GCC/MinGW-W64 doesn't match the calling convention of the implementation in `d2d1.dll`. The return type `D2D_SIZE_F` of GetSize is a struct. According to [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/x64-calling-convention?view=vs-2015#return-values) there are two ways to return a struct from a function:

> User-defined types can be returned by value from global functions and static member functions. To return a user-defined type by value in RAX, it must have a length of 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, or 64 bits. It must also have no user-defined constructor, destructor, or copy assignment operator. It can have no private or protected non-static data members, and no non-static data members of reference type. It can't have base classes or virtual functions. And, it can only have data members that also meet these requirements. (This definition is essentially the same as a C++03 POD type. Because the definition has changed in the C++11 standard, we don't recommend using std::is_pod for this test.) Otherwise, the caller must allocate memory for the return value and pass a pointer to it as the first argument.

When GCC/MinGW-W64 compiles the sample code from the article, the caller only sets up one argument (in `rcx`) for the call to GetSize, and expects the value to be returned in `rax`:

```
# AT&T syntax (destination operand last)
mov 0x10(%rbx),%rcx    # rcx <- pointer to IRenderContext
mov (%rcx),%rax        # rax <- pointer to virtual function table
callq *0x1a8(%rax)     # virtual function call (expect result in rax)
```

In the code generated by Visual Studio, the caller sets up `rdx` to point to a location on the stack before calling GetSize:

```
# Intel syntax (destination operand first)
mov rax,qword ptr [rsp+168h]     # rax <- pointer to IRenderContext
mov rax,qword ptr [rax]          # rax <- pointer to virtual function table
lea rdx,[rsp+68h]                # rdx <- address of return value (hidden argument)
mov rcx,qword ptr [rsp+168h]     # rcx <- this pointer (hidden argument)
call qword ptr [rax+1A8h]        # virtual function call (expect result at [rdx])
```

On GCC/MinGW-W64 the value in `rdx` is not a valid address, so when the implementation of GetSize attempts to store the return value in memory there, an access violation occurs.

`D2D_SIZE_F` is a 64-bit POD struct (just a struct of two floats), so it seems to me that GCC is correct to return it in the `rax` register. I don't know what it is that makes Visual Studio use return-by-pointer, nor, I'm afraid, how to make GCC do the same for compatibility.

Comment: There is now a workaround for this in the mingw-w64 headers ([explained here](https://sourceforge.net/p/mingw-w64/mingw-w64/ci/ee9fc3d0b8c8868280e38384edd968067b8e71fc/)). It's available now if you're using the MSYS2 package sources. For the time being it's necessary to activate the workaround, by defining `WIDL_EXPLICIT_AGGREGATE_RETURNS` before including "d2d1.h".

Comment: It turns out, per the [MSVC ABI docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/x64-calling-convention#return-values) that you cannot use return-by-value with non-static member functions: _"User-defined types can be returned by value from global functions and static member functions."_ So in this case, gcc is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is actually related to a [nine-year-old bug in gcc](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=52792) and unclear or incorrect MS Documentation of the calling convention.

According to that bug report, if the return structure cannot be fit into a register, its pointer will be in RDX (2nd arg), and the called object will be in RCX (1st arg). gcc does it the other way 'round, with return pointer in RCX (1st arg) and called object in RDX (2nd arg).

It's not 100% clear which way is correct per the docs: The [Return Values documentation for C++](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/x64-calling-convention?view=vs-2019#return-values) documentation says to make the return value pointer the first argument. Separately, the [Calling Conventions documentation for Debugging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/x64-architecture#calling-conventions) says that the `this` pointer is passed as an implicit first parameter.

Clearly gcc and MSVC disagree about the order of those two rules being applied. It appears in my limited tested that Clang agrees with MSVC, but I haven't been able to follow the logic fully yet. Clang does seem to treat this situation as a 'thiscall', and [in that case excludes the RCX register](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/blob/a2552f76ac6ff705434adb1d277a578445721b78/llvm/lib/Target/X86/X86CallingConv.td#L650-L657) for [hidden return object pointers](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/blob/8779b114109dd1461a410e2357f2505665e6efec/llvm/include/llvm/CodeGen/TargetCallingConv.h#L32). I haven't worked out how it actually puts the 'this' pointer into RCX though, it's probably not super-important.

Back to this problem, where it's not returning the structure by value. With a small [Compiler Explorer test](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/3qq1hj), the only time that MSVC uses a hidden return value instead of return-by-value in RAX is when it's a member call, *and* it's an object. Clang agrees, and you can see really clearly in the Clang IR that it put the object pointer first, and the hidden-return-struct-pointer second:

```
call void @"?GetPixelSize@ID2D1RenderTarget@@QEBA?AUD2D_SIZE_U@@XZ"(%class.ID2D1RenderTarget* %4, %struct.D2D_SIZE_U* sret %2), !dbg !31
```

The reason I suspect this is related to the gcc bug, is that I am guessing that the underlying issue is the ordering of dealing with moving the "return value pointer" and "this pointer" into the argument list.

gcc (I guess?) processes the called object first, and pushes it as the new first argument. Then it independently looks at the return object, and either returns-by-value, or pushes it as the new-new first argument, leaving the called object ultimately second.

Clang is processing the other way 'round. It processes the return object first, but already knows it's a this-call, which is how it knows to avoid ECX above. If it had already processed the called object pointer, ECX would have been allocated already. However, when deciding if the return is by-value or by-hidden-object-pointer, it clearly already knows that it is dealing with a this-pointer, because that makes the difference.

And knowing that, and hunting backwards from the `CCIfSRet` seen above, I found that Clang [specifically marks that for non-POD return values, *or* Instance methods, the return value is indirect and not by-value](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/blob/8779b114109dd1461a410e2357f2505665e6efec/clang/lib/CodeGen/MicrosoftCXXABI.cpp#L1110). This code is not hit [if the return value is not a structure](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/blob/8779b114109dd1461a410e2357f2505665e6efec/clang/lib/CodeGen/MicrosoftCXXABI.cpp#L1096-L1098), which is why (as seen in Compiler Explorer) a uint64_t doesn't get turned into an indirect return here.

This is also the only place I saw that [explicitly sets that the 'return structure pointer' comes *after* the 'called-object' pointer](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/blob/8779b114109dd1461a410e2357f2505665e6efec/clang/lib/CodeGen/MicrosoftCXXABI.cpp#L1111). I guess every other ABI puts them in the same order as gcc.

(I couldn't check gcc on Compiler Explorer, as there doesn't seem to be a version offered which supports the Win32 ABI, e.g., mingw64 or tdm builds)

This is the same place that ensures the correct order of the two hidden parameters, i.e. avoids the gcc bug that started me on this hunt in the first place.

And now that I know *where* the code is, `git blame` shows me that this was [a known thing about the x64 ABI in llvm 3.5 in 2014](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/commit/40ca913727f914b720b30d4e3ccc66250fb4aba2#diff-f6f568343ad5aef3a8372074bc7027fbR459-R479) although [a bunch of other cases were fixed in llvm 9 in 2019](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/commit/85a0f8fe6c5c8ab35790c40d078d4fa103a5a54a#diff-f6f568343ad5aef3a8372074bc7027fbR1082-R1104).

---

Of course, Clang is not MSVC. It is presumably emulating an observed behaviour of MSVC, but it's possible that the MSVC outcome is just a coincidence of order-of-processing, and it happens to be the opposite of gcc.

---

So while gcc is correct by a strict reading of the ABI docs, it has two mismatches compared to both MSVC (the ABI owner) and Clang around handling hidden arguments for instance methods with aggregate return values. One has been bugged, and this problem is reproducing the other.

---

The [workaround in mingw-w64's headers](https://github.com/mirror/mingw-w64/commit/ee9fc3d0b8c8868280e38384edd968067b8e71fc) functions by making the hidden structure-return-pointer an explicit pointer parameter. This both ensures gcc doesn't try to pass it in a register, and also puts it *after* the hidden called-object parameter.

You can see the [implementation side of the same fix in Wine](https://github.com/wine-mirror/wine/commit/fabfa59aea5c5b3201142382038beb3e76cb7567#diff-5c21affa1cada6cd5502484b39817cd7L488-R489), which was already using an explicit called-object pointer, and so to get the ordering correct, needs to use an explicit return-structure-pointer parameter too.

---

Side-note: I haven't looked into the 32-bit failure.

I had a quick look with Clang (which I don't *know* to be correct here, as Compiler Explorer doesn't appear to offer 32-bit MSVC) and it seems to produce the same call for both `__stdcall` and `__thiscall`, except that the `__stdcall` version saves ECX, but the `__thiscall` version does not. I guess that's just a difference in what the function is allowed to stomp, and what it must restore when it's done.

Based on the [commit description in Clang's history](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/commit/40ca913727f914b720b30d4e3ccc66250fb4aba2) I suspect the same nine-year-old-bug is affecting 32-bit gcc too.

---

Update: Looking at the [Return values documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/x64-calling-convention?view=msvc-160#return-values) months later, I noticed that this limitation *is* documented:

> User-defined types can be returned by value from global functions and static member functions.

So the return-by-value-in-register approach is not supported for member functions, except static member functions, and gcc is not correct per the ABI docs in this case.

Comment: Some background in Raymond Chen's blog entry for today, https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20220113-00/?p=106152

Comment: That's an interesting blog post. It's talking about the x86 ABI, which I didn't look at the docs for (that he mentions are wrong), but my "Side-note"-linked Clang commit suggests that Clang was already matching MSVC, not the docs. Since the original question showed failure on 32-bit as well, I assume gcc there has also implemented the spec, not the de-facto behaviour of MSVC.

Comment: Actually, looking closer, on 32-bit the small-structure return in gcc still ends up as pass-by-pointer, the problem there (per the gcc bug) is that the `this` pointer and the `return location` pointer are exchanged compared to MSVC. It's possible that if that is fixed, this small-structure-return problem will appear to, but it's also possible that gcc is already correctly handling that.