# Getting bogus return values from C macros in Direct2D

Tags: winapi, direct2d

I'm using Direct2D using the C-style interface. This works fine except two functions that return structures, namely `ID2D1Bitmap_GetSize` and `ID2D1RenderTarget_GetSize`. They return a `D2D1_SIZE_F` structure which is 64 bits (it contains two `FLOAT` items). I'm calling them like this:

```
D2D1_SIZE_F sz;
    
sz = ID2D1Bitmap_GetSize(pBitmap);
printf("GOT: %f %f\n", sz.width, sz.height);
    
sz = ID2D1RenderTarget_GetSize(pRenderTarget);
printf("GOT: %f %f\n", sz.width, sz.height);
```

I'm getting bogus values from both `GetSize` calls so it appears that something gets messed up on a register level. Interestingly, somebody seems to have had a similar problem ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34438351/1197719)) but he was on MinGW and C++ and people were saying that it is a MinGW problem. I'm not on MinGW but I'm on an older version of Visual C (15.00.30729.01 for x64) and I don't use C++ but C.

Since nobody probably uses Direct2D from C I think it's quite likely that some of those bridging macros are messed up and don't work from C. Could this be the case here? Is there any way to make this work from C as well?

Comment: You'll need to update the macros to [receive the return value through an extra pointer parameter](http://web.archive.org/web/20171022215635/http:/blog.airesoft.co.uk/2014/12/direct2d-scene-of-the-accident/#note1).

Comment: Thanks a lot! I've hacked `d2d1.h` to include an additional pointer argument and it indeed solved the problem! Has this been fixed in newer SDKs? I'm still on an SDK from around 2012.

Comment: SDK team is working on it, but I'm not sure if the fix is out yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for the record, this is what the fix should look like in `d2d1.h`:

In `typedef struct ID2D1BitmapVtbl`:

```
STDMETHOD_(D2D1_SIZE_F, GetSize)(
   ID2D1Bitmap *This, 
    __out D2D1_SIZE_F *Ptr
   ) PURE;
```

In `typedef struct ID2D1RenderTargetVtbl`:

```
STDMETHOD_(D2D1_SIZE_F, GetSize)(
    ID2D1RenderTarget *This,
    __out D2D1_SIZE_F *Ptr 
    ) PURE;
```

And the macros have to be fixed like this:

```
#define ID2D1Bitmap_GetSize(This, ptr) \
    ((This)->lpVtbl->GetSize(This, ptr))
#define ID2D1RenderTarget_GetSize(This, ptr) \
    ((This)->lpVtbl->GetSize(This, ptr))
```